# Why the bottom text doesn't stick to heading (css)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Problem:
.parc_ned doesn't stick to .parc_name

```css
.parc {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.parc_avatar {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
}

.parc_ned {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.parc_name {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parc">
  <img class="parc_avatar" alt="USER_AVATAR" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
  <span class="parc_name">Lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="parc_ned">Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Here's result:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/776497290390143076/904991557013356594/Screenshot_20211102_091141.jpg

Comment: What is ***stick***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre aligning `.parc_name` to the top by setting `vertical-align:top` but youre missing that same styling for `.parc_ned` so it does not align itself to the top.

By adding `vertical-align:top` to the `.parc_ned` selector it moves to the top. I also added matching `line-height` and `display:inline-block` to both selectors to make the text inside the elements centered to each other.

```css
.parc {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.parc_avatar {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
}

.parc_ned {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parc_name {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parc">
  <img class="parc_avatar" alt="USER_AVATAR" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
  <span class="parc_name">Lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="parc_ned">Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

**In case you didnt want it to be at the top but "stick" to the left of the name you would have to add another div:**

```css
.parc {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.parc_avatar {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
}

.parc_content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.parc_ned {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}

.parc_name {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parc">
  <img class="parc_avatar" alt="USER_AVATAR" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
  <div class="parc_content">
    <span class="parc_name">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span class="parc_ned">Lorem ipsum</span>
  </div>
</div>
```